# Why am I getting a validation error?

Tags: drupal-6

On the node edit page, under file attachments, I'm getting the following error when I click attach:
**Validation error, please try again. If this error persists, please contact the site administrator**

Comment: It's difficult to debug this problem with little information. Please edit and add more information... whether you have custom modules altering the node form, any special modules, form edits from the template, etc.

Comment: This happens on forms that haven't been altered such as the story form /node/add/story

Comment: It's coming from the upload module

Comment: Are you using the default garland theme ?

Comment: No, using a custom theme

Answer (score 0):

More of an expedient work-around, perhaps: I disabled javascript long enough to perform my file upload and then turned it back on.

For the installation where I encountered this error a recursive grep on the modules paths showed this error message in the following paths:

```
modules/upload/upload.module
includes/form.inc
sites/all/modules/ctools/includes/form.inc
sites/all/modules/views/includes/form.inc
```

I encountered the error in the midst of a file upload, and a quick look at the `upload.module` showed the error came from a function called: `upload_js()`.  So I disabled javascript in my browser and uploaded my file and then re-enabled javascript.

Before doing that I ensured that my user had privileges and an ample quota for uploading this < 400kb file, bumped the `max_file_uploads` setting and restarted `php5-fpm/apache`.

The complaining code looks like this:

```
  // Load the form from the Form API cache.
  if (!($cached_form = form_get_cache($_POST['form_build_id'], $cached_form_state)) || !isset($cached_form['#node']) || !isset($cached_form['attachments'])) {
    form_set_error('form_token', t('Validation error, please try again. If this error persists, please contact the site administrator.'));
    $output = theme('status_messages');
    print drupal_to_js(array('status' => TRUE, 'data' => $output));
    exit();
  }
```